# Stuck At flutter gradle build

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, gradle

Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi Note 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

I am stuck at when running app on my android device.
Flutter doctor found no issue and app is running on chrome and edge but not on phone.
Also this is the first time I am running on a physical device

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me: Reboot physical device, `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, build app